# Summary measurement lost when adding mods to rma.glmm

Tags: r, metafor

At this moment I'm trying to calculate the (adjusted)IRLM with the rma.glmm function of the metafor package.

My data is a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
head(data)


 patient-years events    age
1  180.0000  4    NA
2  116.2500 13 51.83
3   66.2500  6 48.00
4  423.6333 21 58.00
5  142.1783  7 53.20
6 1117.3167 72 59.90
```

The function to calculate IRLM works fine:

```
y=rma.glmm(xi=events, ti=patent-years, data=data, measure="IRLN",method="ML")
```

And gives me the following forest plot:

```
metafor::forest.rma (y)
```

[Forest plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISLKP.png)

However, when I want to adjust my model:

```
    nh=rma.glmm(xi=events,ti=patient-years, data=datanh, 
measure="IRLN", mods = ~ age , method="ML")
```

(Where age is a numeric vector)

The summary measure is lost

[Adjusted forest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVq1a.png)

I've tried all I can think of, but really don't know how to fix this. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's easier to help you if you make your question reproducible including data and your code which can be used to test and verify possible solutions Check out [mre] and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a moderator to the model, there is no longer *the* effect (or to be precise, the average effect in a random-effects model). The size of the average effect then depends on the value of the moderator. The gray-shaded polygons in the forest plot then reflect the estimated average effects corresponding to the values of 'age' for the included studies.

You could compute the predicted average effect for a particular value of age with the `predict()` function, i.e.,:

```
predict(nh, newmods = <age value>, transf=exp)
```

(`transf=exp` to obtain the estimated average IR for the specified age value).

Some might plug the average of the age values observed in the studies into  and interpret this as an adjusted estimate. One can debate whether this terminology ('adjusted effect') is correct.